# Not able to receive messages from different scenes

Tags: game-engine

I'm creating a tank game in blender game engine in which a scene shoud get the message with the score from another one but it is not working. I have tried sending the message to an object in the same scene and it works. ( By the way I am using blender 2.70.)

Comment: The Blender Game Engine has been discontinued, you may be better off migrating to Unity, Unreal or Godot

Comment: There is not this possibility in blender game, you must write what you need to send on a file and open that file once you have switched scene to read your data. If you want to know there is armory 3d which is the 'next gen' version of bge, get into it !